# If $XY-ZW=I_{n}$ and $XW+ZY=0$ show that $YX-ZW=I_{n}$ , $WX+YZ=0$ and $\det(XY)\geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$X,Y,Z,W \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$$ with $n>2$, $$n\in\mathbb{N}$$
If $XY-ZW=I_{n}$ and $XW+ZY=0$ show that $YX-ZW=I_{n}$ , $WX+YZ=0$ and $\det(XY)\geq 0$

I know that $XW=-ZY$ but I have no idea how to continue and prove the above. Could you help me please ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to prove $YX-WZ=I_n$ (rather than $YX-ZW=I_n$)?

Comment: You got me interested in this problem. Most of it is fairly easy: leave $\mathbb R$ (go to $\mathbb C$), define $A=X+iZ$ and $B=Y+iW$ and conclude that $AB=I_n$, which implies $BA=I_n$ etc.... However, I don't seem to see yet why $\det(XY)\ge 0$ - hope someone will come up with the full solution. Note that your statement needs to be corrected as per my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Incorporating the correction suggested by Stinking Bishop, we want to show that if $X,Y,Z,W \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ are such that
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
&XY-ZW=I
\qquad\qquad\qquad
\\[4pt]
&XW+ZY=0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
then
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
&YX-WZ=I
\qquad\qquad\qquad
\\[4pt]
&WX+YZ=0
\\[4pt]
&\det(XY)\ge 0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Assume the hypothesis.

Following the approach outlined in Stinking Bishop's comment, if $A,B$ are given by
\begin{align*}
A&=X+iZ
\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\,
\\[4pt]
B&=Y+iW
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
&
AB=(X+iZ)(Y+iW)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
AB=(XY-ZW)+i(XW+ZY)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
AB=I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
BA=I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(Y+iW)(X+iZ)=I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(YX-WZ)+i(WX+YZ)=I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\begin{cases}
YX-WZ=I\\[4pt]
WX+YZ=0\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which establishes the first two parts of the desired conclusion.

It remains to show $\det(XY)\ge 0$.

If $X$ or $Y$ is singular, then $\det(XY)=\det(X)\det(Y)=0$, and we're done.

So assume $X,Y$ are nonsingular.

From the equation $XW+ZY=0$, we get $W=-X^{-1}ZY$, hence
\begin{align*}
&
XY-ZW=I
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
XY-Z\bigl(-X^{-1}ZY\bigr)=I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
XY+ZX^{-1}ZY\bigr)=I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
XY+\bigl(ZX^{-1}ZX^{-1}\bigr)\bigl(XY\bigr)=I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(XY)(I+T^2)=I
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where $T=ZX^{-1}$.

From $(XY)(I+T^2)=I$, we get that $I+T^2$ is nonsingular.

Since $I+T^2$ is nonsingular, we get that $\det(I+iT),\det(I-iT)$ are nonzero.

Since $T$ is a real matrix, we get that $\det(I+iT),\det(I-iT)$ are complex conjugates.

It follows that $\det(I+T^2) > 0$, hence from $(XY)(I+T^2)=I$, we get $\det(XY) > 0$.

This completes the proof.